# Do we use RPC or SSH for inter process communication in hadoop?

Tags: hadoop, ssh, rpc, hadoop2

While reading fourth chapter of the **Definitive Guide for Hadoop** book, I found following sentences :

```
In Hadoop, interprocess communication between nodes in the system is implemented using remote procedure calls (RPCs). The RPC protocol uses serialization to render the message into a binary stream to be sent to the remote node, which then deserializes the binary stream into the original message.
```

And I knew that we use password-less **SSH** for communication amongst machines.

Can someone explain me what do we use **RPC** or **SSH** for inter process communication? Please clarify my doubts.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13909603/why-do-we-need-hadoop-passwordless-ssh

Answer (score 0):

**Hadoop** Deamons are **Java** **processes**, Which will be communicating through **RPC**. SO Java Objects go pass throgh the network in **Serialized** object form. 
**SSH**, or Secure Shell, is a protocol used to **securely** log onto **remote** **systems**. It is the most common way to access remote Linux and Unix-like servers, such as VPS instances

Comment: Do you mean that ssh or tunnel is used by RPC for inter process communication? Means network level communication first gets established via ssh and then on top of it RPC does inter process communication.